# Having difficulty calling a POST on my Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm simply trying to add a record to a database via a Web API.

I call it as such:

```
localhost/X/api/Awards/directors/add?awardTitleId=1&personId=10078261&nameId=1651&isOnBallot=1&whoEntered=0&whoChanged=0
```

Route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "AddDirector", routeTemplate: "api/awards/directors/add/{id}", defaults: new
      {
          controller = "Awards", action = "addDirector"
      });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void addDirector(int awardTitleId, int personId, int nameId, bool isOnBallot, string whoEntered, string whoChanged)
    {
      myConnection.Open();
      var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.AWD_Directors (AwardTitleId, PersonId, NameId, IsOnBallot, WhoEntered, WhoChanged) VALUES (" + awardTitleId + ", " + personId + ", " + nameId + ", " + isOnBallot + ", " + whoEntered + ", " + whoChanged + ")";
      var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      myConnection.Close();
    }
```

When I try to do this on Fiddler:

```
../X/api/Awards/directors/add?awardTitleId=1&personId=10078261&nameId=1651&isOnBallot=1&whoEntered=0&whoChanged=0
```

I get the following message back:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to create a Web API controller in the same way you'd create an MVC controller. One of the ideas with Web API is that it uses convention to map the HTTP verbs to the methods. So in order to allow a POST, your method name just needs to begin with "Post...".

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is, but you should remove the `{id}` from your route, as you don't have a parameter called `id`. Also, post the rest of your controller code as it may be hitting the wrong method for some reason? And is the `X` in your Url a virtual directory? or an area?

Comment: And try Route Debugger. It's great! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to create a Web API controller in the same way you'd create an MVC controller. One of the ideas with Web API is that it uses convention to map the HTTP verbs to the methods. So in order to allow a POST, your method name just needs to begin with "Post...".

As such, the route is not supposed to include the verb at all. The route, and hence the URL, should just end at the controller name. The method to call on the controller can then be determined either by the naming convention or the use of the attributes (such as `HttpPost`). So using the default route template of `api/{controller}/{id}` and removing the 'add' portion of your URL should help.

Please see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations for a complete example.

Comment: It is a convention that webapi maps verbs top the method name, but it isn't a requirement. Decorating a method with the `System.Web.Http.HttpPost` attribute will still allow a post (and deny a get).

Comment: True. The thrust of my answer was to redirect the OP from trying to have verbs in the route to following the normal Web API conventions. I will edit to make that more clear.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, the `add` in the url is unnecessary as the http verb `POST` should be sufficient... and more 'RESTful' too. Just wanted to point out it wasn't required.